# How to catch ThreadAbortException in C# when Thread.Abort is called while C++-Code is running?

Tags: c#, c++, exception, threadabortexception

I have a long running function in a C++-DLL. I start this function from C#-code.
In C#-code I call the function in an own thread.

Now I want to abort the thread. The `ThreadAbortException` occurs. The native function stops. But I'm not able to catch the Exception. The necessary code in the `catch` clause is never executed.

Here is the code how I call the native function:

```
    [DllImport(DllFileName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "LongRunningNativeFunction", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.I4 )]
    public static extern int LongRunningNativeFunction();

    public static int LongRunningFunction()
    {
        try
        {
            int ret = LongRunningNativeFunction(); // <== here occurs the exception
            return ret;
        }
        catch ( System.Threading.ThreadAbortException e )
        {
            // THIS DOES NOT CATCH THE EXCEPTION
            return 2001; // <== this never happens, but it should
        }
    }
```

And here is the code how I handle the thread:

```
            object value = null; 
            Thread thread = new Thread(
                () => 
                {
                    value = ThreadProc();
                });
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            errorCode = (int)value;
```

with ThreadProc:

```
        public void ThreadProc()
        {
            _errorCode = LongRunningFunction();
        }
```

How is it possible to handle the exception? When the exception occurs the errorCode is *not* 2001 but 0. But I need 2001 as return value.

Comment: Don't abort the thread. Use cooperative cancellation instead. Your exception handler would run on the same thread that just got aborted. The only place where you could handle that exception is in an exception handler surrounding `thread.Join()`. Throwing exceptions is very expensive though and messy, which is why cooperative cancellation is always preferred

Comment: _"... ThreadAbortException is a special exception that can be caught, but it will __automatically be raised again__ at the end of the catch block...."_ see- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadabortexception?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You haven't tested this well enough.  The CLR cannot abort a thread that is busy running native code.  Thread.Abort() will block while the CLR periodically tries to gain control, the most likely outcome with code like this is that it completes normally.  Making native code abortable requires running it in a separate process so you can Process.Kill() it.

Comment: @Panagiotis: I have searched for "cooperative cancelation" and found one example. Perhaps it is an idea. I will think about.

Comment: There's a lot more than just one example. It's a *very* common technique. It means that instead of stopping a thread by aborting, you set a signal that the thread monitors periodically to tell it to exit gracefully. One way to do this would be with an OS-level AutoResetEvent or ManualResetEvent.

Comment: In fact, why would that method throw a ThreadAbortException if *your* code didn't call `Thread.Abort` ? How was this exception thrown?

Comment: @Richard: Yes, I know. But it looks like the catch block is never reached. The line `return 2001` is never reached (as mentioned in the code). When the exception is raised **_at the end of the catch block_**  then the line **_in_** the catch block should be touched, or not?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Of course `Thread.Abort`is called by the application. If the 'LongRunningNativeFunction' needs too much time for processing then it should be possible to terminate it.

Comment: @Hans: How shall I test it better? When 'Thread.Abort' is called the LongRunningNativeFunction returns, so it is be completed in whatever way. And the exception occurs, but is not catched. But I will think about the idea to start it in a new process instead of a new thread.

Comment: @user9462004 in that case did yo check Hans' links to the docs? It shows how to avoid rethrowing. It's still a bad practice though, even in C code. What is `LongRunningNativeFunction` ? Your own method? A method provided by a library? If it's your own method it can be modified to use synchronisation events. If not, `Thread.ResetAbort()` may be your only choice